# Changing color of objects based on the color as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop

I have made simple drag-and-drop color buttons where if user drag the specific buttons, it will detects the color based on the what user drag and apply it to the object where user drop the color into. However, I can't figure it out why the color keep changing to black whenever I chose a button and drag and drop it to the single object in the scene, it will turn black even though I already have define the color of buttons.

How can I solve this?

Here is the code that I am using (I am using this on CS6):

```
var array_objects:Array = new Array(firstRectangle_mc, secondRectangle_mc, thirdRectangle_mc, fourthRectangle_mc);
var hit_object:Array = new Array();

var color_x:int;
var color_y:int;

addListeners(red_btn, black_btn, yellow_btn);

function addListeners(... objects):void
{
    var color:Array = new Array("0xFF0000", "0x000000", "0xFFFF00");

    for (var i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
    {
        var input:TextField = new TextField();

        input.text = color[i];
        input.visible = false;

        objects[i].addChild(input);

        objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onColorMouseDown);
        objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onColorMouseUp);
    }
}

function onColorMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    hit_object = [];

    color_x = e.currentTarget.x;
    color_y = e.currentTarget.y;

    e.currentTarget.startDrag();
}

function onColorMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();

    for (var i:int = 0; i < array_objects.length; i++)
    {
        if (e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(array_objects[i]))
        {
            hit_object.push(array_objects[i]);
        }
    }

    e.currentTarget.x = color_x;
    e.currentTarget.y = color_y;

    var changeColor:ColorTransform = hit_object[hit_object.length - 1].transform.colorTransform;

    changeColor.color = e.currentTarget.text;

    hit_object[hit_object.length - 1].transform.colorTransform = changeColor;
}
```

Here is the link of the demo:

[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tyc8z74vguv3r63/Untitled-1.swf?dl=0)

Your answer much appreciated!

Thank you very much

Comment: You're trying to assign a string value to the integer var. It will result in 0, so your color will be always black. You should use:
`changeColor.color = parseInt(e.currentTarget.text, 16);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see at this line:

`changeColor.color = e.currentTarget.text;`

`e.currentTarget` is a circle. What is `e.currentTarget.text`? Circle doesn't have a `text` property. It has a child `TextField`. So, if you want to get text from TextField you must write:

`e.currentTarget.getChildAt(1).text;`

Circle have two children: Shape and TextField. So `getChildAt(1)` = `TextField`.

---

You can do it without TextField. See:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
{
    objects[i].color = color[i];
    objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onColorMouseDown);
    objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onColorMouseUp);
}
```

Circle it's a MovieClip. The MC it's a dynamic class, that means that you can add any property to it. In our case, we add a `color` property.

Next:
`changeColor.color = e.currentTarget.color;`
Understand?

---

In your code I have found a bug:

```
var changeColor:ColorTransform = hit_object[hit_object.length - 1].transform.colorTransform;
```

If you stop dragging circle and circle doesn't hitTest any boxes the error appears:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
```

To avoid this, add condition:

```
if (hit_object.length)
{
    var changeColor:ColorTransform = hit_object[hit_object.length - 1].transform.colorTransform;

    changeColor.color = e.currentTarget.color;

    hit_object[hit_object.length - 1].transform.colorTransform = changeColor;
}
```